# Pass variable to query used in a Neo4j apoc.do.case procedure

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

In this query I want to check the validity of the `$accountId` and `$userId` parameters, and if they are valid then create a new project attached to the User and Account nodes.

```
optional match (u:User {id:$userId})
optional match (a:Account {id:$accountId})
call apoc.do.case([
   not exists((u)-[:ACCOUNT_ADMIN]->(a)),
   "return {error:'user is not admin of the specified account'} as result",
   "match (u:User {id:$userId})-[:ACCOUNT_ADMIN]->(a:Account {id:$accountId})
      create (a)-[:CONTAINS]->(:Project {name:$projectName})<-[:PROJECT_ADMIN]-(u)
      return {result:'project created'} as result",
   {accountId:$accountId, userId:$userId, projectName:$projectName}
)
yield value
return value.result as result
```

It appears to work, but does not strike me as very elegant. What is particularly irksome is that in the `else` query passed to `apoc.do.case` I have to execute another `match` to relocate the nodes I've already located in the outer `optional matches`.

Is there no way to reuse the `u` and `a` variables that I've already located in the `optional match`'s within the `apoc.do.case` `else` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this? Apart from the parameters, I think you should use  `apoc.do.when`

```
optional match (u:User {id:$userId})
optional match (a:Account {id:$accountId})
call apoc.do.when(
   not exists((u)-[:ACCOUNT_ADMIN]->(a)),
   "return {error:'user is not admin of the specified account'} as result",
   "with $a  AS a,$u AS u create (a)-[:CONTAINS]->(:Project {name:$projectName})<-[:PROJECT_ADMIN]-(u) return {result:'project created'} as result",
   {u:u,a:a, projectName:$projectName}
)
yield value
return value.result as result
```